# Angle between two points in degrees

Tags: geometry

Is there a more practical function to get an angle between two points? I do this, but I think very extensive ...

```
ponto1 = {6, 2}; ponto2 = {10, -14};
angListPos[p1_, p2_] := 
 N[Mod[ArcTan @@ (p2 - p1), 
   2 Pi]/°](*Ângulo entre dois pontos em graus*)
angListPos[ponto1, ponto2]

gp1 = {PointSize[0.03], Point[ponto1]};
gp2 = {PointSize[0.03], Point[ponto2]};
l = Line[{ponto1, ponto2}];
Graphics[{gp1, gp2, l}]
ang = N[ArcTan[(ponto2[[2]] - ponto1[[2]])/(ponto2[[1]] - 
      ponto1[[1]])]/°]
```

[image]

Comment: What is an "angle between two points"?

Comment: Maybe you mean `VectorAngle`

Comment: As corey says, "angle between two points" sounds... off. I gather from your code that you're getting the angle between two segments with one endpoint at the origin. But, do you always want the small angle, or the large angle? (Personally, I'd want the angle between the positive $x$-axis and the line $y=-x$ to be 45 ° (with a negative sign if the application demands it).)

Comment: @corey979 Excuse me. The angle between two points with the horizontal.

Comment: @yode Yes. like this.

Comment: Could you make a schematic drawing showing which angle you want to obtain? It's unclear for me what you want to achieve. Your `angListPos[ponto1, ponto2]` and `ang` are different things, `VectorAngle[ponto1, ponto2]` gives a third value, and `ArcTan @@ (ponto1 - ponto2)` is different from all of them.

Comment: `ponto1 = {6, 2}; ponto2 = {10, -14};
VectorAngle[ponto2 - ponto1, {1, 0}] 180./Pi`

Comment: `ArcTan @@ (ponto2 - ponto1)/Degree // N`

Comment: @LouisB That's just `ang`.

Comment: Maybe create a list of results to use the first function or another association